# Creating mutidimensional array consisting of asterisks

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic

I am new to programming and I want my program to run a table consisting of stars(asterisks). E.g. table 4x3 has 4x3 stars. But my initial problem is that I do not know how to implement a multidimensional array in such a way that I just need to change the initial value of rows and columns in order to create more or less stars.

So: here is my code at the moment:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Multidimensional_array
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arrayRows = 4;
            int arrayCols = 3;

            int[,] arrayTimes;
            arrayTimes = new int [arrayRows, arrayCols];
            //String star = "*";

            for( int i = 0; i <= arrayRows; i++) {
                for( int j = 0; j <= arrayCols; j++) {
                    //Console.WriteLine("*");
                    //arrayTimes[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

So I just want that if I change the int arrayRows to 5 and int arrayCols to 5 then I receive a star table of 5x5. T

Comment: Subscripts in C# are zero-based, i.e. when you create an array of 4 elements the subscripts range from 0 to 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close, you're just using the wrong data type for your array, haven't assigned the `*` to each position in said array, and your current code would give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. You may have 4 rows and 3 columns, but array indices are zero-based, meaning when you access positions 1, 2, 3, etc. you use an index of 0, 1, 2, etc. respectively.

So, since you want to store the text "*", you should use a `char[,]` or a `string[,]` for your multi-dimensional array. I've chosen `char[,]` for this:

```
int arrayRows = 4;
int arrayCols = 3;

char[,] arrayTimes = new char[arrayRows, arrayCols];
const char star = '*';

// Set it up
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayRows - 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= arrayCols - 1; j++) 
    {
        arrayTimes[i, j] = star;
    }
}

// Print it out
for (int i = 0; i <= arrayRows - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= arrayCols - 1; j++) 
    {
        Console.Write(arrayTimes[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

- [**Working ideone sample**](http://ideone.com/VaSQiG)

Comment: Yes yes... thank you very much sir. I am not sure why you have to initialize "const char". Is that good practice for a programmer? to be honest, I also do not really understand the functionality of const.

Comment: `const` is short for `constant`. A very simplified explanation is that if you have a variable you don't want allowed to change after it is defined, then you can prefix its declaration with `const`. For example, if, between the two for-loops, you tried to write `star = '#';`, the compiler would disallow it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Get the number of rows
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows:");
            int arrayRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Get the number of columns
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columns:");
            int arrayCols = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // For each item in the row
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
            {
                // For each item in the column
                for (int j = 0; j < arrayCols; j++)
                {
                    // Show a star
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                // End the line
                Console.WriteLine(""); 
            }

            // Read the line to stop the app from closing
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

If you want to store the stars

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Get the number of rows
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of rows:");
        int arrayRows = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Get the number of columns
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of columns:");
        int arrayCols = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        // Create an array
        char[,] arrayTimes = new char[arrayRows, arrayCols];
        char star = '*';

        // For each item in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
        {
            // For each item in the column
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayCols; j++)
            {
                // Show a star
                arrayTimes[i, j] = star;
            }
        }

        // Read the line to stop the app from closing
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This do what you want,

```
        int arrayRows = 2;
        int arrayCols = 2;

        char[,] arrayTimes;
        arrayTimes = new char[arrayRows, arrayCols];
        //String star = "*";

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayCols; j++)
            {

                arrayTimes[i, j] = '*';
                Console.Write("{0}",arrayTimes[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I was very close haha... thank you very much for the short and concise answer.

Comment: NP. Yep, You were so close. Most of us stuck like that... Good Luck